# Understanding “es sich gut gehen lassen”

Tags: german-to-english, phrase

I've seen various translations for the phrase *es sich gut gehen lassen,* including:

- *to take care of oneself*
- *to have a good time*

Can someone provide a definition (or definitions?) of this phrase, and, hopefully, usage notes?

Answer (score 3):

This is the common usage:

> Im Urlaub will ich es mir richtig gut gehen lassen.

In Germany, there's a special kind of additional vacation you can go on every few years on a prescription of your doctor. It's called *Kur* and you usually do this in a spa town. These even have it in their name, they are called *Bad …*. That's why *es sich gut gehen lassen* can also have the connotation of taking care of oneself.

So *to have a good time* isn't *exactly* what this phrase means, as it usually excludes anything stressful, as going to amusement parks or taking your children with you.

Dressing up nicely and visiting a Casino (Spa towns often have those) may in contrary fit into that phrase.

Comment: *Kur* prescriptions were very common for elderly (but still working) people in the 1980s and at that time they were indeed sometimes perceived as a form of extra holidays (paid by health insurance). My impression is however that starting with the late 1990s policies changed, and prescriptions for *Kur* do need some much more substantial justification than just *es sich gutgehen lassen*; now, I think, *Kur* prescriptions are always related to seriuos conditions, e.g. recovering after heavy surgery or cancer treatment.

Answer (score 3):

As Janka pointed out the common phrase usage, I want to point out that both of your translations can fit and not only taking care of yourself.

In general it means "what I think is a good time for me and/or my body I will do". Nothing you would do on a daily base, nothing you could effort on a daily base.

examples:

- to take care of your own body in a Spa - and impliying that this is not your daily body care routine

  - in this sense it could also mean a weekly "mini selfmade Spa at home"
- to go on a vacation where all daily duties are done by someone else thus enjoying what you (the vacationer) would call luxury (thus doing it quite seldom, combined with "sich etwas leisten")
- to have fun and don't care much about other opinions that you might waste your money

It still could be that someone enjoys this "gut gehen lassen" for a whole year, it still is a luxury living way compared to the rest of the life thus seldom.

And could mean anything else then luxury in money terms because for some people simply taking / having time to do something they want to do (in their dreams) would be "gut gehen lassen".

Answer (score 1):

Let oneself have a good time. Compare to "sich was gönnen" or swedish "att unna sig något".

To allow yourself (to) something nice or tasty or healthy (which might be expensive or otherwise questionable).